# Exclude headers when importing Google Spreadsheet content with Roo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-sheets, roo

I created a rake task to import users from a Google Sheet. Therefore I am using the gem '[Roo](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo)'. Everything works so far but I can't seem to get it working without importing the first row (headers).

This is my code:

```
require 'roo'

namespace :import do
  desc "Import users from Google Sheet"
  task users: :environment do

    @counter = 0
    url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/{mycode}/export?format=xlsx'
    xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(url, extension: :xlsx, headers: true)
    xlsx.each do |row|
        n = User.where(name:row[0]).first
        user = User.find_or_create_by(id: n)
        user.update(
                     name:row[0],
                     country_id:row[6]
                   )
        user.save!
        puts user.name
        @counter += 1
      end
     puts "Imported #{@counter} lines."
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code says `headers: true` when you are opening the sheet. Have you tried turning it to false? Or are you saying it does not work when it's set to false?

Also, you are using `.each` rather differently than the example in the documentation. The doc shows a hash with keys derived from the headers. You are using `[n]` array notation. Does that work?

EDIT:

Try using `.each` in a way that's more similar to what the documentation says:

```
xlsx.each(name: 'Name', country_id: 'Country ID') do |row|
  n = User.where(name: row[:name]).first
  ...
end
```

The strings 'Name' and 'Country ID' are just examples; they should be the text of whatever column headers have the name and country_id information.

Comment: I've tried true, false, first_row but nothing worked so far.

Comment: Edited my answer with another suggestion. It's not really a surprise that `headers: false` is not working; it is listed in the docs as an option for `.parse` but you are trying to use it in `.open`.

Comment: Thanks! I reused `.each` from an old project where I've imported from an csv instead of a spreadsheet. I rewrote it but unfortunately the headers are still imported.

Comment: OK, you could also just skip the first line, right? `xlsx[1..-1].each`

Comment: I was so focused on the headers that I didn't think about skipping the first row entirely. Unfortunately your suggestion leads to the following error `NoMethodError: undefined method [] for #<Roo::Excelx:0x00007f9c2858bd50>`

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to skip the headers, it is using the method: `each_row_streaming(offset: 1)`.

It will return an array with rows skipping the header, so you have to get the value using `.value` method. In documentation specify it for `Excelx::Cell` objects, but it works for `Roo::Spreadsheet` objects too.
The [documentation](https://github.com/roo-rb/roo) example:

```
xlsx.each_row_streaming(offset: 1) do |row| # Will exclude first (inevitably header) row
  puts row.inspect # Array of Excelx::Cell objects
end
```